# Is there a smaller extension field than the algebraic closure which satisfy that every polynomial in it splits

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field.

I already know that there is an algebraic closure $\overline{F}$ of $F$
which satisfy that every $f(x)\in \overline{F}[x]$ is splits in $\overline{F}[x]$.

Is there a **smallest** extension field $E$ of $F$ such that every $f(x)\in {\mathbf F}[x]$ is splits in $E[x]$?
Or such extension field $E$ must be the algebraic closure of $F$?

Comment: The algebraic closure is the smallest such extension by definition.

Comment: Which raises the question; what is *your* definition of an algebraic closure?

Comment: @AlexG. The ``smallest'' means that every $f(x)\in  \overline{F}[x]$ is splits in $\overline{F}[x]$.
But I only want to every $f(x)\in {\mathbf F}[x]$ is splits in $E[x]$.

Comment: @Servaes The algebraic closure of $F$ is an algebraic extension of $F$ which is algebraically closed.

Answer (score 4):

Let $E$ be the smallest extension of $F$, where every polynomial  in $F[X]$ splits. Then $E$ is algebraically closed, i.e., every polynomial in $E[X]$ splits as well: Consider $f\in E[X]$. Its finitely many coefficients are in a *finite* algebraic extension $K$ of $F$ (presumably smaller than $E$). If we multiply together all the (finitely many) conjugates of $f$, we obtain a polynomial that is in fact in $F[X]$, so splits by assumption; consequently its factor $f$ splits as well.

This argument uses Galois theory; if you don't have enough of it available, you may have to gnaw yourself through the base of $K/F$ step by step ...

Comment: Thank you.
Which book can I find the detail of this argument. 
Like the definition of the conjugates of $f$ and the base of $K/F$, etc.

Comment: If you are learning field-theory and field-extensions from any book, it should be in there, I guess

Comment: I find out the conjugate of an element (another root of its minimal polynomial), and the conjugate of an algebraic extension (its image under a automorphism). But I can't find any definition about the conjugate of a polynomial $f$. Could you please give me a definite book name or is there another name of the conjugate of a polynomial.
Thank you very much.